# Implementing breakpoints on variable value changes during step debugging without conditional breakpoint

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, debugging, xdebug, xdebug-3

Is there an effective method to pause execution during step-by-step debugging when a specific variable's value is altered, without the prerequisite of establishing a conditional breakpoint in advance?

Take, for instance, the practice of monitoring variables through the watch functionality while conducting step debugging. Is there a mechanism that automatically stops execution at the exact moment a watched variable's value is modified?

Such a feature would enable a more efficient debugging process, allowing for an immediate transition to the segment of code responsible for the change, thereby eliminating the need for extensive code inspection.

I am particularly interested in identifying the precise line in my code that modifies the value of a custom cookie named `IS_APP` within the `$_COOKIE` superglobal amidst a complex framework. Before embarking on an in-depth examination, I am curious to know if such a debugging capability exists.

Comment: You should tag your language, is this PHP?